# When is scons "Depends" useful when compiling c/cpp files?

Tags: c++, linux, scons, depends

Any c/cpp files can call functions defined in other module, only linking phase resolve them. These c/cpp files don't depend on each other for compiling sequence.

So my question is, is there any case that one c/cpp file should depend on another one, so that we need to specify in SConstruct like:

```
hello=Program("hello.c")
Depends(hello,'other_file')
```

Thanks!

Comment: For `.c` files? Probably never... can you be more specific as to the problem you've encountered?

Comment: `Depends` is useful (sometimes) when you write custom builders and stuff like that. If you're using SCons for mainstream languages and activities, it might not be directly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be useful to force dependencies which SCons may not be aware of.
For example you may use

```
env.Command('a.xyz','b.abc','do_stuff.sh $SOURCES -o $TARGET')
```

It may be a simple command but you know it depends on a file "templatefile.wxy".

You can either write a full builder with Scanner (which would probably be overkill in this case). Or use Command + Depends.